# ReferenceError : File is not defined

Tags: reactjs, file, unit-testing, mocha.js, enzyme

I am doing react unit testing using mocha and enzyme. I'm checking whether data passed is an instance of File

```
if (data instanceof File) {}
```

What package should I import/require in order for this to work?

Note: The code works actually, it's only during testing that I'm having problems

Comment: If you are running test outside a browser env, try to change this to `data instanceof windowFile` or `global.File`

Comment: In addition to @keul: Use JSDOM, see https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/jsdom.md - or abandon mocha and use jest which nicely integrates JSDOM.